# Why do max and min get called after subscription yields values?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a collection of objects that I need to know what the number range is before I process any items in the collection. I came up with code similar to what is below, and it seems to give the correct answer:

```
var arr = Rx.Observable.fromArray([10,-10,4,-5,20,4,7]),
//In actual code this is an array of objects, so have a custom compare function
numberComparer = function(a,b) { return a-b; };

//In actual code this is prefixed by a filter and mapping operation 
arr.flatMap(function(x) {
    return Rx.Observable.zip(
        arr.max(numberComparer), 
        arr.min(numberComparer), 
        function(max, min) { 
            return { 
                stats: {max: max, min: min}, 
                item: x
            };
        }
    );
})
.subscribe(function(item) { 
    DoStuffWithItem(item.item, item.stats); 
});
```

But I'm a bit confused about what is going on behind the scenes. The comparer functions are giving the right answers when the first item is yielded to the subscribe method, but then they continue to be called between item yields.

Here is a [JSBin showing what I mean](http://jsbin.com/cumemenege/1/edit?js,console). Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a better, more Rx-y way to do this? What I was expecting to happen was that the max and min values would be computed first, and then the subscription function would be invoked with no other calls to max or min.

**Edit**: It looks like maybe the behavior is that it is continuously recomparing with what hasn't been output yet, which explains partially why I'm seeing the behavior. I just don't understand why it is doing that (and how to make it stop) :)

Comment: Hmm, because you use `flatMap`, `zip` operator will be called as many times as number of elements in collection. I don't know how you want to use this code, but maybe `combineLatest` can do the job? [See example](http://jsbin.com/qopomobevu/2)

Comment: We are making a visualization that takes each item and classifies it based on where it falls in the whole set, so the min/max gets passed in at same time as the value. I tweaked your example a bit to make it work this way, still not sure if this is "better" than calculating the min/max out of the RX chain and then just passing it in though. [see example](http://jsbin.com/demevewuzi/2/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is on the right track. I would recommend the use of `when()`  `and` and `thenDo` instead though, it should have the same behavior, but you can more clearly convey your intent and you don't have to worry about synchronization.

```
    var minMax = Rx.Observable.when(
    filteredArray.max().and(filteredArray.min())
    .thenDo(function(x, y) { 
      return { max : x, min : y};
    }));

    minMax.flatMap(function() {
          return filteredArray;
    }, function(stats, x) {
          return {stats : stats, value : x};
    });
```

Here is a [modifed version](http://jsbin.com/giruvotuba/1/edit?js,console) of the example.

Since this is not the most efficient way to compute minMax because you are running through the array twice, you could further optimize by creating your own minMax operator with `reduce()`.

```
Rx.Observable.prototype.minMax = function(comparer) {

  var source = this,
      c = comparer || function(x, y) {
    return x - y;
  };


  return source.reduce(function(seed, x) {

     if (c(x, seed.min) < 0) (seed.min = x);
     if (c(x, seed.max) > 0) (seed.max = x);

    return seed;

  }, {min : Number.MAX_VALUE, max : Number.MIN_VALUE });

};
```

Comment: Thank you, that also addressed the a concern I had about iterating through the whole list twice to get the max and min independently. Looks good!